# How to use the `where` method along with the `with` method in laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Given the following, very simple, example:

**Country Class**

```
class Country extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = "countries";
    protected $fillable = array(
        'id',           
        'name'
    );

    public function state() {
        return $this->hasMany('State', 'country_id');
    }   
}
```

**State Class**

```
class State extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = "states";
    protected $fillable = array(
        'id',           
        'name',
        'country_id' #foreign
    );

    public function country() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Country', 'country_id');
    }
}
```

How can I list all the states, based on the `id` or the `name` of the country.

Example:

```
State::with('country')->where('country.id', '=', 1)->get()
```

The above returns an area, as `country` is not part of the query (Eloquent must attach the join later, after the where clause).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're either misunderstanding the relations or over-complicating this.

```
class Country extends Eloquent {
    public function states() {
        return $this->hasMany('State', 'state_id');
    }   
}

$country = Country::find(1);
$states = $country->states()->get();
```

Comment: I was over complicating it! Thanks

Comment: Followup question - any way of doing this with `all`. For example `Country::all()->states()->get();`